# Calculus - Derivatives and Tangent Lines

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the equation of the lines (there's 2) tangent to the graph of $f(x) = x^3$ and parallel to the line $12x − y + 1 = 0$.

So far obviously the slope of the line must be $12$.
The equation of the line tangent to $f(x) = x^3$ is the derivative and must be equal to the slope of the intersecting line, $12$. The derivative of $x^3$ is equal to $2x^2$, so $2x^2 = 12$, and $x=$ $\pm\sqrt{6}$, so $y$ must equal to $\pm6\sqrt{6}$ and thus the equation of the line is $y=12x-6\sqrt{6}$ or $y=12x+6\sqrt{6}$. Is this correct? Thanks.

EDIT

I think I made a mistake it should be  $y=12x-5\sqrt{6}$ or $y=12x+5\sqrt{6}$

EDIT again

Thanks to everyone who helped out!
The derivative is equal to $3x^2$ not $2x^2$, so $x =\pm 2$ and so $y =\pm 8$ so plugging back into the equation gives $y=12x-16$ or $y=12x+16$, right?

Comment: check that derivative again.....

Comment: Note that $(x^3)'\not=2x^2$.

Comment: $$y=x^3 \\y'=3x^2\\3x^2=12\\x^2=4\\x=+2,-2$$

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be equal to 3x^2 right?

Comment: @MathisFun: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out!

Comment: @MathisFun Please add your solution as an answer and accept the answer instead of editing your original question. This way we can avoid having our unanswered questions queue contain this answered question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the slope of our line(s) needs to be $12$ to ensure they are parallel to the line
$\,12x − y + 1 = 0.$

Next, finding the derivative of $y = x^3$ gives us $\,y' = 3x^2$.

To find the points on the curve at which the tangent lines at those points have slope $12$, we solve $$3x^2 = 12 \iff x^2 = 4 \iff x =\pm 2.$$

**Following your edits:** Yes, you are correct.

There are two lines tangent to the curve $y = x^3$ with slope $12$. One point at which a line with slope $12$ is tangent is given by $(-2, -8)$ and the other point at which a line with slope $12$ is tangent to the curve is given by $(2, 8)$.

So you have slope $m = 12$, and a point $(x_0, y_0)$ for each of two such tangent lines.

$$(y - y_0) = m(x - x_0)$$

Hence, one line is given by $$y + 8 = 12(x + 2) \iff y = 12 x + 16$$

The other line is given by $$y - 8 = 12(x -2) \iff y = 12x - 16$$